# Mediaplayer throws Error(-38,0) on reset()- and prepareAsync()-call

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have this piece of code:

```
    try
        {
            mMusicPlayer.reset();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathToTitleFile);
            mMusicPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            mMusicPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
```

When I skip a song, sometimes I get two Error/error(-38,0).
I've debugged it and the errors were thrown at the following code-section:
The error(-38,0) after the reset()-call. The Error(-38,0) after the prepareAsync()-call.
After this the player calls the onPrepare()-callback and jumps back and performs the try-block again. This repeats a few times before the song is played.
Strange thing is, that I don't get any other information about the error and error (-38,0) seems to be a "generic-error".

Answer (score 0):

Based here [MediaPlayer reset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset%28%29)

Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. After calling this method, you will have to initialize it again by setting the data source and calling prepare().

You need to initialize MediaPlayer again.

Comment: From the MediaPlayer class: 
Calling setDataSource(FileDescriptor), or setDataSource(String), or setDataSource(Context, Uri), or setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long, long) transfers a MediaPlayer object in the Idle state to the Initialized state.

...as I do. :)

Comment: I should mention that the error doesn't occur on every skip. mostly it works perfect.